# Is this code for a calculator efficient?

Tags: java, beginner, algorithm, calculator

```
package standardcalculator;

/**
*
* @author BSK
 */
public class calculator2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private String input="";//We have nothing to display on the screen,if we dont do this creates the problem of displaying the null.
    private String firstOperand="0"; //Standard firstOperand.
    private String previousResult = "";//for storing the previous result.
    private String operation="noOperation";//initialy noOperation.
    /**
    * Creates new form calculator2
    */
    public calculator2() {
        initComponents();
    }  
    private void commonAction(String inpt){
        input += inpt;
        displayscreen.setText(input);
    }
    private boolean isFirstOperand(){
        return firstOperand.equals("0");
    }
    private void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        commonAction("1");
    }                                       

private void button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    commonAction("2");
}                                       

private void button3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   commonAction("3");
}                                       

private void button4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   commonAction("4");
}                                       

private void button5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
  commonAction("5");
}                                       

private void button6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    commonAction("6");
}                                       

private void button7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   commonAction("7");
}                                       

private void button8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   commonAction("8");
}                                       

private void button9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
  commonAction("9");
}                                       

private void button0ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   commonAction("0");
}                                       

private void buttonDotActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    commonAction(".");
}                                         

private void butMulActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    operation = "multiply";
    double result;
    input = displayscreen.getText();
    if (input.equals("")){

    }
    else if ( isFirstOperand()){
        firstOperand = input;
        previousResult = firstOperand;
        displayscreen.setText("");
    }
    else{
        result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult);
        result *= Double.parseDouble(input);
        displayscreen.setText(result+"");
        previousResult = result+"";
        firstOperand = "0";
    }
    input=""; //As we have stored the input now we need new input ,i.e,the new variable.
}                                      

private void butDivideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    operation = "divide";
    double result;
    input = displayscreen.getText();
    if ( input.equals("")){

    }
    else if ( isFirstOperand()){
        firstOperand = input;
        previousResult=firstOperand;
        displayscreen.setText("");
    }
    else{
        result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult);
        result /= Double.parseDouble(input);
        displayscreen.setText(result+"");
        previousResult = result+"";
        firstOperand = "0";
    }
    input=""; //As we have stored the input now we need new input ,i.e,the new variable.
}                                         

private void butMinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    operation = "minus";
    input = displayscreen.getText();
    double result;
    if ( input.equals("")){

    }
    else if ( isFirstOperand()){
        firstOperand = input;
        previousResult=firstOperand;
        displayscreen.setText("");
    }

    else{
            result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult);
            result -= Double.parseDouble(input);
            displayscreen.setText(result+"");
            previousResult = result+"";
            firstOperand = "0";
        }
    input=""; //As we have stored the input now we need new input ,i.e,the new variable.
}                                        

private void butAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    operation = "add";
    input = displayscreen.getText();
    double result;
    if ( input.equals("")){

    }
    else if ( isFirstOperand()){
        firstOperand = input;
        previousResult=firstOperand;
        displayscreen.setText("");
    }
    else{
            result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult);
            result += Double.parseDouble(input);
            displayscreen.setText(result+"");
            previousResult = result+"";
            firstOperand = "0";
        }
    input=""; //As we have stored the input now we need new input ,i.e,the new variable.
}                                      

private void butEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    double result;   
    if ( input.equals("")){

    }
    else{  
        switch(operation){
            case "add":
                result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) + Double.parseDouble(input);
                displayscreen.setText(result+"");
                break;
            case "minus":
                result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) - Double.parseDouble(input);
                displayscreen.setText(result+"");
                firstOperand="0";
                break;
            case "multiply":
                result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) * Double.parseDouble(input);
                displayscreen.setText(result+"");
                firstOperand="0";
                break;
            case "divide":
                result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) / Double.parseDouble(input);
                displayscreen.setText(result+"");
                firstOperand="0";
                break;
            case "modulus":
                result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) % Double.parseDouble(input);
                displayscreen.setText(result+"");
                firstOperand="0";
                break;
            case "reciprocal":
                result = 1/Double.parseDouble(previousResult);
                displayscreen.setText(result+"");
                firstOperand="0";
                break;
            case "root":
                result = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(previousResult));
                displayscreen.setText(result+"");
                firstOperand="0"; 
                break;  
            case "noOperation":
                break;
       }
    }
}                                         

private void displayscreenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    //input=displayscreen.getText();
}                                             

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new calculator2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton butAdd;
private javax.swing.JButton butDivide;
private javax.swing.JButton butEquals;
private javax.swing.JButton butMinus;
private javax.swing.JButton butModulus;
private javax.swing.JButton butMul;
private javax.swing.JButton butReciprocal;
private javax.swing.JButton button0;
private javax.swing.JButton button1;
private javax.swing.JButton button2;
private javax.swing.JButton button3;
private javax.swing.JButton button4;
private javax.swing.JButton button5;
private javax.swing.JButton button6;
private javax.swing.JButton button7;
private javax.swing.JButton button8;
private javax.swing.JButton button9;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonDot;
private javax.swing.JTextField displayscreen;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Here are the conditions that I have covered:

- The multiply button is pressed again and again.
  If we have not input and pressing the multiply button.
- Repeatedly multiply without pressing the "=" key. Note: Input is given and shown in `textField` each time user enter a button, I did not show the code for that.

My question is about the readability of the code, and my applied algorithm. Is it efficient?

Please keep patience as I am new to Java and learning to design the algorithm, and please provide me some references about how to design an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Would you consider using Java 8? Just for my suggestions...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry!whats nice about that one.

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1 :** Reduce different event handlers which performs almost same task.

**How:**

**Step 1.1:** The button click events (button1ActionPerformed and similar others) which are calling the commonAction method, delete all except 1 method.

**Step 1.2:** Analyze the event variable of the event you kept. It should have information about the button, get the text of the button and pass it as a parameter of commonAction method

**step 1.3:** For the other button's click events, attach the same event for all of them.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class calculator2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
```

The class names should be UpperCamelCase, so it will be `Calculator2`.

Why Calculator **2**? What means this two? Maybe you should choose another name or just `Calculator`.

```
javax.swing.
```

You can avoid to rewrite the full package using [`import`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

```
private String input="";//We have nothing to display on the screen,if we dont do this creates the problem of displaying the null.
private String firstOperand="0"; //Standard firstOperand.
private String previousResult = "";//for storing the previous result.
private String operation="noOperation";//initialy noOperation.
```

I dubt they need all to be `String`s. Why `operation` operation is a `String`? With your code you force it to be Java7+ only while you could use an `enum` with all operations and make your code looks better, or use a `char` so if your calculation have button "+" you can put this value directly inside the variable (but an `enum` is more flexible and allow you to do more edits), with strings you could write "multiply" wrong and it will not work.

Instead of `noOperation` string what about `null` ?

```
firstOperand
previousResult
```

They work like double but they are Strings, why? You need to convert it to double everytime, use `double`!

Inside `butMultiActionPerfomed`:

```
if (input.equals("")){

}
```

If you don't need this block why you do it?

If you don't want to execute the code if `input` is empty, change your code to:

```
private void butMulActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
operation = "multiply";
double result;
input = displayscreen.getText();
if (input.isEmpty()) {
  return;
}
```

So if the input is empty it will block the execution of the method.

The same for other methods.

You should avoid to avoid to repeat code, all this methods `butDivideActionPerformed`/`butMulActionPerformed`/`butMinusActionPerformed`/`butAddActionPerformed` do the **same thing**.

You should change your code to use a method which will perform the change of the `operation` variable.

In the same method this block

```
else{
  result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult);
  result -= Double.parseDouble(input);
  displayscreen.setText(result+"");
  previousResult = result+"";
  firstOperand = "0";
}
```

It will be different based on the current action. You can avoid it and use the same method which is called when `=` is called.

```
butEqualsActionPerformed
```

Same for others. The code which will perform the operation should be inside another method so you can call it inside the other methods `add`, `min` etc. and avoid to repeat the code.

About the events which will add the numbers etc. i don't know how it's done in Java but in Android i would set a `tag` to the Button which contains what it should add and add one onClick to all which will read this tag to understand what value should be added. Check if `ActionEvent` can carry with it some custom objects.

---

It's how you could edit your code

```
private void executeAction(String operation) {
    // save operation
    this.operation = operation;

    // it's empty, so ignore it
    if (!input.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    if (isFirstOperand()) {
        firstOperand = input;
        previousResult = firstOperand;
        displayscreen.setText("");
    }
    else {
        executeCalculation();
    }

    input = "";
}
```

`executeAction` will be called by your `butMulActionPerformed`/`butDivideActionPerformed` etc. example:

```
private void butDivideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    executeAction("divide");
}
```

`executeCalculation` is the method which will be called when you need to execute the operation.

```
private double executeCalculation() {
    double result = 0;
    switch(operation){
        case "add":
            result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) + Double.parseDouble(input);
            break;
        case "minus":
            result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) - Double.parseDouble(input);
            break;
        case "multiply":
            result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) * Double.parseDouble(input);
            break;
        case "divide":
            result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) / Double.parseDouble(input);
            break;
        case "modulus":
            result = Double.parseDouble(previousResult) % Double.parseDouble(input);
            break;
        case "reciprocal":
            result = 1/Double.parseDouble(previousResult);
            break;
        case "root":
            result = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(previousResult));
            break;
        case "noOperation":
            break;
    }

    firstOperand="0";
    return result;
}
```

and your `butEqualsActionPerformed` will be

```
private void butEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (!input.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    double result = executeCalculation();
    displayscreen.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

p.s other things you could improve: why `executeAction` should do `displayscreen.setText("");` ?

Remember to follow Java naming style! `displayscreen` should be `displayScreen`!

Comment: How can i have common method for `butDivideActionPerformed/butMulActionPerformed/butMinusActionPerformed/butAddActionPerf` when = is pressed?I want to take into account that case in which user adds two numbers and after that,without pressing =,he pushes + for adding another value and repeat it multiple times and i want to show each result on screen.Problem is that i want to display the result without pressing = if we have add after add operation.

Comment: i can take all my instances as `double` but i choose `String` as display is in the form of String

Comment: Thanx in advance in making my life easier and please also mention about the idea of `enum` and `char`.How `enum` is flexible?

Comment: Since enums are full classes, you could add an enum with all operations and a method execute which will contains the operation between two numbers. In this way you could have more "abstraction" and get away the switch.

Comment: `why executeAction should do displayscreen.setText("");?` Because next time when the user enter first operand the screen holds the first operand then user  presses operation button then it will not harm to `input = displayscreen.getText();` otherwise extra digits will be caught by this.

Comment: No sorry, i mean: It can be done by the caller, the executeAction should't care about this.

Comment: i think it is mandatory for executeAction() to do `displayscreen.setText("");` due to my previous reason.

Comment: That's ok. It's just a my idea. If you think it's the right place for it is ok. The important thing you should consider is that: supposed one day you use executeAction for another thing, you will still want to do this?

Comment: hmmm! i will try your brilliant ideas , thanx a lot.But tell me one thing personally,Do you feel i can code better by looking at my program?please tell me truely.

Comment: and what about if i carry all the updates required in a separate function at the end of the operation?

Comment: If you want you can program everything. That's just a question of experience. I don't understand what you mean, but try to do the change you want and see how it works :)

Answer (score 2):

**N.B. these suggestions require Java 8**. Although they can be used in earlier Java versions by using `interface`s to implement the Strategy pattern - Effective Java item 21.

The first thing to note is that your are constantly turning `String` into `double` and back. Just use `double` throughout for your numeric values.

You have a lot of duplicate code. Most of your code is the same thing copy/pasted with a few things changed.

Lets start with the number buttons - there are ten that are **exactly** the same. Start by changing the `commonAction` method to something like this:

```
private void pressNumber(double number) {
    input += number;
    displayscreen.setText(input);
}
```

Now, using Java 8 lambdas we can rewrite the creation all the buttons to this:

```
private List<JButton> createNumberButtons() {
    final List<JButton> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        final int num = i;
        final JButton number = new JButton(Integer.toString(num));
        number.addActionListener(e -> pressNumber(num));
        numbers.add(number);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

You can now assign the buttons in the `List` to your original variables, or change your GUI to use the new `List`. Each button calls `pressNumber` with its index `i`. This means you can remove all of the button action methods.

Now onto your operator. Don't use a `String`, use an `enum`. This is exactly the sort of thing they were intended for. Using Java 8 function interfaces and some more lambdas we have this, rather neat, impl:

```
private static enum Op implements DoubleBinaryOperator {
    PLUS(Double::sum),
    MINUS((a, b) -> a - b),
    TIMES((a, b) -> a * b),
    DIVIDE((a, b) -> a / b),
    MODULO((a, b) -> a % b),
    RECIPROCAL((a, b) -> 1 / a),
    SQRT((a, b) -> Math.sqrt(a));

    private final DoubleBinaryOperator op;

    Op(final DoubleBinaryOperator op) {
        this.op = op;
    }

    @Override
    public double applyAsDouble(final double left, final double right) {
        return op.applyAsDouble(left, right);
    }
}
```

Now we need to a common, "operator" method that applies the selected `Op` to the numbers. Something along these lines ought to do:

```
private void operatorButtonAction(final Op op) {
    operation = op;
    if (displayscreen.getValue() == null)
        return;
    if (isFirstOperand()) {
        firstOperand = Double.parseDouble(input);
        previousResult = firstOperand;
        displayscreen.setText("");
    } else {
        final double result = op.applyAsDouble(previousResult, Double.parseDouble(input));
        displayscreen.setValue(result);
        previousResult = result;
        firstOperand = 0;
    }
    //As we have stored the input now we need new input ,i.e,the new variable.
    input = "";
}
```

So rather than hardcoding the selected operator, we have parametrised it out. Again, this is a strategy pattern.

Now your operator button methods look like:

```
private void butMulActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    operatorButtonAction(Op.TIMES);
}
```

In short, you need to think much more about what is *common* across the code. Not what is *different*. Try and apply design patterns to your code to clean it up. This example is predominantly using the Strategy Pattern.

Comment: :Sorry i am new to java,can i directly start with java8?

Comment: @Bayant_singh Java 8 is the newest version of Java; hot off the presses almost. If you're learning Java, it's probably be to learn Java 8 and it **significantly** enhances Java's capabilities.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some good source,a good book will be appriciated.thank you for your support.

Comment: @Bayant_singh The [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) are always a good place to start. There is also a [book from Manning](http://www.manning.com/urma/).

Comment: thanx a lot for your valuable thoughts